# Use NSNumber and NSUserDefaults to do a simple computation

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, nsuserdefaults, nsnumber

I have a view where a user enters an amount. Using NSUserDefaults, this amount is transferred to the next view, where I wish to do a mathematical computation with it. In this next view, I have a mutable array that is used for adding data to a table. What I want is:

Label in view 2 = NSUserDefaults - (all array objects added together)

I figured out how to add the array objects together: `NSNumber *sum = [transactions valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];`.

I tried to do the math, but no luck: `self.amountLeftInBudget.text = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AmountToSpend"] - sum];`. I got this error: Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'id', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit:** My code (using an alert view)

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //Only do the following actions if the user hit the done button
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSString *amountSpentTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;

        if (!transactions)
        {
            transactions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }

        [transactions insertObject:amountSpentTextField atIndex:0];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

        [self.mytableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        //Add all the objects in the transactions array
        NSDecimalNumber *sum = [transactions valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];

        //Get the user defaults from the amountToSpend field
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSDecimalNumber *amountToSpend = [defaults objectForKey:@"AmountToSpend"];

        // Set the amountLeftInBudget label THE PROBLEM! the subtracting does not work
        [self.amountLeftInBudget setText:[amountToSpend decimalNumberBySubtracting:sum]];

        //Set the amountSpent label
        [self.amountSpent setText:[sum stringValue]];
    }
}
```

The problem in trying to subtract the two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine your expression, on the left-hand-side of `-` you have:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AmountToSpend"]
```

What is the *value* of that expression? It is some reference to an object. Now the rhs is:

```
sum
```

and the *value* of that expression is some reference to an `NSNumber`. So what is the `value` of:

```
<some reference to an object> - <some reference to an `NSNumber`>
```

You are asking for the difference between two references, hence the error: *Arithmetic* on pointer to interface 'id', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform.

You need to obtain the numeric value your objects represent, do your arithmetic on those, and then convert the numeric result to a string representation to assign it to your `text` property.

`NSNumber` has various methods to obtain the numeric value the object represents; e.g. `doubleValue`, `intValue`, etc.; and you need to select the appropriate one depending on your needs.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes a lot of sense. How would I get the value of user defaults?

Comment: @ShaanSingh CRD answered that in the last paragraph.  If you don't know how to get the numeric value from an `NSNumber`, I'd suggest stepping back for a moment and reviewing some of the fundamentals of the language.

Comment: Those can be used for NSUserDefaults too?

Comment: @ShaanSingh - If you know the object returned from `NSUserDefaults` is an `NSNumber` then you can use `NSNumber` methods on it. However you don't need to, look up "Getting Default Values" in the documentation for `NSUserDefaults` - you can get a selection of types directly using methods such as `stringForKey:` etc.

Comment: @ShaanSingh - now you have not *parsed* the strings you have as numbers, the string `@"9"` does not have the `int` value 9 anymore than the string `@"XI"` does - they are both character representations of 9. Assigning an arbitrary object returned by `objectForKey:` to an `NSDecimalNumber *` variable does not convert the object - as you found in your case an `NSString` reference was returned and simply stored. Look up the methods `doubleValue` (on `NSString`) and `doubleForKey:` (on `NSUserDefaults`). You seem to have some basic misunderstandings; take bbum's advice and review the fundamentals.

Comment: I looked up the methods you suggested and tried some code. I also tried @spinacher's solution, which led to a crash. @CRD could you help me out with this line: `[self.amountLeftInBudget setText:[amountToSpend decimalNumberBySubtracting:sum]];`. I had tried `[self.amountLeftInBudget setText:[amountToSpend doubleValue decimalNumberBySubtracting:sum]];`

Comment: @ShaanSingh - You **need** to go back to fundamentals and figure out the difference between value types, objects, string representations of values etc. The line you refer to is but part of your problem. What does the definition of `valueForKeyPath:` say it returns? An `NSNumber *` and yet you assign it to an `NSDecimalNumber *`. What is an `NSNumber` anyway and how it it different from a `double` (both are mentioned in the description of `valueForKeyPath:`)?

Comment: Okay, I am to go read up on some of this and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the text on a UILabel you have to give it an NSString. So the line that you flag as a problem won't work...

```
// Set the amountLeftInBudget label THE PROBLEM! the subtracting does not work
[self.amountLeftInBudget setText:[amountToSpend decimalNumberBySubtracting:sum]];
```

...because you're giving UILabel an NSDecimalNumber. Convert the NSDecimalNumber into a string first:

```
[self.amountLeftInBudget setText:[[amountToSpend decimalNumberBySubtracting:sum] stringValue]];
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the app crashes. The problem may be the NSUserDefaults. What do you think?

Comment: My answer assumes that amountToSpend is a valid NSDecimalNumber object retrieved by your code from NSUserDefaults in the preceding line.  You can check this assumption by setting a breakpoint and using the debugger to inspect amountToSpend and confirm that it is an NSDecimalNumber.  I think you may not be correctly writing the NSDecimalNumber to NSUserDefaults to begin with. As an aside, it is a bit unusual to use NSUserDefaults to pass variables around like this; you might find it easier just to make amountToSpend an instance variable.